# event.PreventDefault(); Doesn't work inside nested onClick function

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.7, jquery-click-event

I'm submitting my data to controller using ajax function which return the result perfectly but the problem is ajax post the data multiple time while click event is fired.
Note that, my function structure is in this order:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.editapp', function() {
    // ................
    $(document).on('click','.JustClick', function(e){
      // .................
    })
  })
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.editapp', function() {
    var app = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var appeal_id = $(app).find('input[name="appeal_id"]').val();
    var dataStr = 'appeal_id=' + appeal_id;

    $(document).on('click', '.JustClick', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // default action us stopped here   
      $.ajax({
        url: "/swalReturn/" + appeals_id,
        type: 'POST',
        //dataType: 'application/json',
        data: dataStr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          Swal({
            title: 'Prison History',
            type: 'info',
            html: data,
          })
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          swal("Error!", "Check your input,Please!", "error");
          $('.editapp').modal('hide');
        }
      });
    });

  });
});
</script>
```

Click event should fire once and ajax request should for that particular record only not with previous cached data (only clicked item)

Comment: Do you have click events on any parent elements? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Yes I do. I am using modal to update records and using ajax post method for submitting value to the controller. On that modal, I have anchor tag with id and class="JustClick". Now I would like to fire this "JustClick" event after loading the modal and before submitting the form data to the controller via ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','.editapp', function() {
................
   $(document).one('click','.JustClick', function(e){ //.one() method solved my issue
.................
  })
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline your click events, use variables that are in the same scope to pass the values between the click events

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var app, appeal_id, dataStr;
    $(document).on('click', '.editapp', function() {
      app = $(this).attr('data-target');
      appeal_id = $(app).find('input[name="appeal_id"]').val();
      dataStr = 'appeal_id=' + appeal_id;

    });
    $(document).on('click', '.JustClick', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // default action us stopped here   
      $.ajax({
        url: "/swalReturn/" + appeals_id,
        type: 'POST',
        //dataType: 'application/json',
        data: dataStr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          Swal({
            title: 'Prison History',
            type: 'info',
            html: data,
          })
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          swal("Error!", "Check your input,Please!", "error");
          $('.editapp').modal('hide');
        }
      });
    });
  }); </script>
```

Also make sure you are not placing this code in a php loop

Comment: How can I get value for app, appeal_id variable? since DOM are loaded only when I click on '.editapp' class. Here variables are loaded from bootstrap modal and this modal is in foreach loop.

Comment: app, appeal_id variables are global variables and should be accessible to the second click event

Comment: @madalinivascu `app, appeal_id` are **not** global variables in your code, you declare them using `var app, appeal_id, dataStr;' in an anonymous function, and as of that, they are in that scope and not in the global scope.

Comment: yes it is accessible to second click event but I need to have value on app, appeal_id before click on the second event ('.JustClick'). I'm not getting the value on global variable and value is only available after firing the first click event('.editapp').

Comment: can you provide your html

Comment: isn't `.editapp` the button that opens the modal? and `.JustClick` is a button in the modal?

Comment: Absolutely  it is as you said.

Comment: so you will always have values for `app, appeal_id` when you click `.JustClick`